# which keyboard is used at LUKS decryption?

Tags: keyboard-layout, luks

my keyboard layout is being switched from default when i'm on the LUKS decryption screen.  i've tried typing with the most obvious choices, but since my keyboard input is hidden, i have no way of knowing which one i'm in.

i have seen other questions on how to set my keyboard layout for LUKS, which would be great... if i could log in at all.

is there ANY way of getting to ANY other screen from the LUKS page, such that i can get feedback on keyboard input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system (Ubuntu 20.10), this is how i solved it:

Restart the computer and go to the GRuB bootloader, select "Ubuntu (advanced options)", and boot ubuntu in recovery mode.

Ubuntu will boot with more raw terminal output.  Enter in the LUKS password; after 3 bad attempts, it will timeout for 60 seconds.  *Now* your keyboard will output to the screen (although none of it will be interpreted by the shell).